# Cakephp: Model can't be loaded in controller

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I have a model called "Specialite" and i want to load it in MissionController action but it dosen't work.
I put this code  `$this->loadModel('Specialite');` inside the action and when i make a debug: `debug($this->Specialite->find('all'));` no data is returned !!
While the table specialites in DB contains data..
This is the Model class of Specialite :

```
 <?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * Specialite Model
 *
 * @property Filiale $Filiale
 * @property Formation $Formation
 * @property Laboratoire $Laboratoire
 */
class Specialite extends AppModel {

/**
 * Validation rules
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $displayField = 'nom';
    public $validate = array(
        'nom' => array(
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
    );

    //The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed

/**
 * hasMany associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Filiale' => array(
            'className' => 'Filiale',
            'foreignKey' => 'specialite_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        ),
        'Formation' => array(
            'className' => 'Formation',
            'foreignKey' => 'specialite_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        ),
        'Laboratoire' => array(
            'className' => 'Laboratoire',
            'foreignKey' => 'specialite_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        ),
        'Client' => array(
            'className' => 'Client',
            'foreignKey' => 'client_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        )
    );

}
```

When I load other Models the `find()` works pretty fine !! Only and Only with "Specialite" model it refuses to work ! :'( 
I really need help ! Thanks in advance !

Comment: instead of `debug()` try `print_r()` and post back if still nothing shows. The least, it will show an empty array.

Comment: I tried that and it shows an array , something like that :  Specialite Object ( [displayField] => nom [validate] => Array ( [nom] => Array ( [notempty] =>...

Comment: and i tried  pr($this->Specialite);  also it shows Specialite Object( [displayField] => nom
    [validate] => Array
        (.... 
..

Comment: Which means `find()` is somehow working. Can you ensure you have data in your DB. If you do, then you need to post your model class setup for `Specialite` so I can try to see if I notice anything out of normal.

Comment: sorry for being late , i had an issue..                                                                             yes am sure that the table in DB isn't empty ! Here is the class model of Specialite:                                                                                                  <?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');                                                               class Specialite extends AppModel {   public $displayField = 'nom';
 public $validate = array(
  'nom' => array(
   'notempty' => array(
    'rule' => array('notempty'),       ),
  ),
 );

Comment: the rest of the model class Coz the comment dosen't support too much -_-  public $hasMany = array(
  'Filiale' => array(
   'className' => 'Filiale',
   'foreignKey' => 'specialite_id',
   'dependent' => false,
   'conditions' => '',
   'fields' => '',
   'order' => '',
   'limit' => '',
   'offset' => '',
   'exclusive' => '',
   'finderQuery' => '',
   'counterQuery' => ''
  ),

Comment: 'Formation' => array(
   'className' => 'Formation',
   'foreignKey' => 'specialite_id',
   'dependent' => false,
   'conditions' => '',
   'fields' => '',
   'order' => '',
   'limit' => '',
   'offset' => '',
   'exclusive' => '',
   'finderQuery' => '',
   'counterQuery' => ''
  ), 'Laboratoire' => array(
   'className' => 'Laboratoire',
   'foreignKey' => 'specialite_id',
   'dependent' => false,
   'conditions' => '',
   'fields' => '',
   'order' => '',
   'limit' => '',
   'offset' => '',
   'exclusive' => '',
   'finderQuery' => '',
   'counterQuery' => ''
  ),

Comment: 'Client' => array(
   'className' => 'Client',
   'foreignKey' => 'client_id',
   'dependent' => false,
   'conditions' => '',
   'fields' => '',
   'order' => '',
   'limit' => '',
   'offset' => '',
   'exclusive' => '',
   'finderQuery' => '',
   'counterQuery' => ''
  )
 );

}

Answer (score 0):

Please check debug mode in Config/core.php if set 0 than change it to 1 like:-

```
Configure::write('debug', 1);
```

Comment: debug works well with other models , only with Specialite model ! Configure::write( 'debug' , 2); i have this in Config/core.php